# EF Core - Update Entity in Controller after it was modified in Method | How to apply manual Changes above automatic Workflows?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have an action "Save". This action loads an "Order" Entity from the DB and applies possible changes by the User. Every time this action is executed it also runs "UpdateOrderStates" and that´s where the problems begin.
When I use this Method, my changes in the action itself will be overwritten in the Method and I cannot change them anymore.

```
public IActionResult Save(MyViewModel model){
 var order = context.Orders....
 
 if(model.MyState !=null && model.MyState !=order.MyState){
  order.MyState=model.MyState;
 }
 //more stuff....

    await workflow.UpdateOrderStates(model.orderId);
   //context.Update(order);
    context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

 public void UpdateOrderStates(int orderId){
   var order = context.Orders....
   var subOrders = order.SubOrders;
   var subOrdersStateAll = subOrders.All(x=>x.MyState=="DONE");
  //.....
   if(subOrdersStateAll) order.MyState ="DONE"; //There are way more states and options for each state

  context.Update(order);
  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

When I follow this I can see that the order gets updated in the if and then after the "workflow.UpdateOrderStates()" is done, the "MyState" in order will be reset to the one in the Method. I thought that I can fix it with "EntityState.Modified", but apparently not.

1.) What do I have to do to take the object I have in my action and not the data which has been updated by the Method?

2.) Do you perhaps have an idea how to make this so that the manual and automatic Changes work together? ie.: This only would have the correct State after the first save, but when I save it a second time and I do not change anything in MyState (only the description) then the State will be overwritten by the Method, although I would like to keep the State, the User set. And this "UpdateOrderStates" is being used in multiple places....

Comment: EF Core has no workflows. A DbContext already is a Unit-of-Work. All chances are tracked and persisted all at once, in a single transaction, when `SaveChangesAsync` is called. If you call `SaveChanges` after every modification, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: First of all, `UpdateOrderStates` shouldn't be calling `SaveChangesAsync` at all. That's equivalent to committing the Unit-of-Work. Second, `context.Entry(order).State = EntityState.Modified;` isn't needed if the `order` is modified in any way. The `order` value was loaded from the DbContext so it's already tracked by it. Any changes to its values will get persisted.

Comment: Additionally, unless `context.Orders....` is actually `context.Orders.Find(someID)`, the action and `UpdateOrderStates` end up querying the database twice to load the same object. `Save` has already loaded an `order` object. On the other hand, `Find` loads and caches the entity by key, so multiple calls to `Find` will return the same object

Comment: I am mostly using Single() and Where() to get the object. So, what are you saying? How do you recommend to use an object in a Method when the object was already loaded in an above Method? Using the Object itself as an Parameter instead of the ID? However, I just found an similar Error, where I use the Object, update one of it´s values, call SaveChanges, and then the old data gets saved...

Comment: It's hard to say how to fix this because the actual code is missing. `UpdateOrderStates` doesn't seem to have any use here. If all you want is to change the status of the `Order`, do so in the `Save` method. Since you already have an `order` loaded, you can use `(if (order.SubOrders.All(x=>x.MyState=="DONE")){ order.MyState ="DONE";}`. EF will convert `order.SubOrders.All....` into a SQL query and return `True` or `False`

Comment: it´s there because i have to run it after each object that can affect it is changed. As I have written, i have way more States, If I would write that then I would practically have the Workflow in this action too.

Comment: `i have to run it after each object` If all it does is check the value of all suborders, it's not needed and only causes problems. I showed how it can be replaced with a single `if`, removing the extra database call and the concurrency bugs